# Adding several lines of HTML to page using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have an HTML page that displays some information. In javascript, I have a var submitted, that as you can see below, will add a line of text to my HTML if it meets a certain condition.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
if (submitted == "yes") {       
    document.write("<div>SHOW ONLY IF SUBMIITED</div>");
}
</script>
```

Thing is, I want to add several lines of HTML code to my page and I've come to understand that document.write is not the appropriate method to do this. However, every alternative I've found doesn't seem to work for me.

Here's a snippet of the HTML I want to add:

```
<form>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Surname</td>
        <td>Given name</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
         <td><input type="text" name="ln" value=""/></td>
         <td><input type="text" name="gn" /></td>
    </tr>
</table>
</form>
```

The full code is much longer.

My page:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
if (submitted == "yes") {       
    document.write("<div>SHOW ONLY IF SUBMIITED</div>");
}
</script>
<body>
<div class="Title" style="display:block; width=100%;">
    <h1>FORM TITLE</h1>
</div>
     <div id="injecthere"></div>

..... the rest of my html code
</body>
```

The code needs to be injected on page load, not by any input from the user (no buttons, etc)

How can I add my code to my HTML page WITHOUT jQuery (basic java only pls)?

Comment: `I've come to understand that document.write is not the appropriate method to do this` -- *Why have you come to understand that?*

Comment: Could you not just do `document.write` multiple times? Or inside the `document.write`, have multiple lines of code?

Comment: What if you just included the div on the page and then change its visibility conditionally?  https://stackoverflow.com/a/3961649/102937

Comment: This is why: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4537963/what-are-alternatives-to-document-write

Comment: If you'd read through that question/answers you will have noted all the other options you can use. Are neither `innerHTML` or `insertAdjacentHTML` working?

Comment: No, none are working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `.innerHTML` property of the element

```js
var submitted="yes"
var code=`<form>
<table>
<tr>
<td>Surname</td>
<td>Given name</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><input type="text" name="ln" value=""/></td>
<td><input type="text" name="gn" /></td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>`;
if (submitted == "yes") {       
    document.querySelector("body").innerHTML+=code
}
```

```html
<body></body>
```

Comment: this gives me an error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null

Comment: can you show what html element you are appending to

Comment: It does! How would I then format this to make it readable as I have several lines of code that i would rather not compress into a single line?

Answer (score 1):

Here' a way to do it that employs javascript's "template literal" syntax -- using backticks (`) -- to enclose your markup.

```js
function addStuff(){
  const formHTML = `
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td>Surname</td>
        <td>Given name</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><input type="text" name="ln" value=""/></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="gn" /></td>
      </tr>
    </table>`;
  const newForm = document.createElement("form");
  newForm.innerHTML = formHTML;
  document.querySelector("body").appendChild(newForm);
}
```

```css
#existing-content { 
  height: 50px; 
  width: 400px; 
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid gray;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="addStuff()">Append HTML to Page</button>
<div id="existing-content">Existing content</div>
```

If you want to support browsers that don't support template literals, you might end up using tedious iterations of `createElement` (and/or `createTextNode`) with `appendChild` to add each node to the DOM one at a time, starting with the most deeply nested element and working your way out.

If for some reason your page doesn't have a `body` element, this would work to find what element to append the new markup to:
`document.querySelector("#existingContent").parentNode.appendChild(newForm);`

Answer (score 0):

You have the js property innerHTML. So it will look like:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  if (submitted == "yes") {       
    document.getElementByID("myDivID").innerHTML = '<form><table><tr><td>Surname</td><td>Given name</td></tr><tr><td><input type="text" name="ln" value=""/></td><td><input type="text" name="gn" /></td></tr></table></form>';
  }
</script>
<div id="myDivID"></div>
```

Comment: This gives me an error; document.getElementByID is not a function

Answer (score 0):

Basically what you want to do is designate a DOM element that you can inject the dynamically built HTML into - you do that by setting or appending to it's `innerHTML` property:

```js
const buttonEl = document.querySelector('#htmlBtn');
const targetEl = document.querySelector('#target');
let divId = 0;
buttonEl.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
  //innerHTML is what you want to use instead of document.write
  targetEl.innerHTML += `<div id=dynamic-html-${divId}>Added HTML  ${divId}</div>`;
  divId += 1;
});
```

```html
<input id="htmlBtn" type="button" value="Add some HTML to the DOM" />
<div id="target"></div>
```

Answer (score -1):

```js
var submitted = "yes";

function showFormIfNeeded() {
  if (submitted === "yes") {
    var form = document.getElementById("myForm");
    form.style.display = "block";
  }
}
```

```css
#myForm {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
</head>
<body onload="showFormIfNeeded()">
  <form id="myForm">
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td>Surname</td>
        <td>Given name</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><input type="text" name="ln" value="" /></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="gn" /></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Try this

Comment: This doesn't really solve my problem. I don't want that button to show unless submitted = yes and that brings me right back to the same problem I have in the first place, I can't use document.write to inject html code, only text.

Comment: And when do you want to check that submitted == "yes" ? On page load?

Comment: thast right, its a variable obtained by the url through POST